# Using monitor to show mean value of a variable in the last X ticks

Tags: netlogo

I'm working on a simple model where herbivores gain weight (live-weight-gain) when they eat grass, and the quality and quantity of grass varies seasonally. The model has 4 seasons, and each season lasts for 92 days (ticks), so 4 seasons x 92 days = 368 days = 1 year.

I have a monitor that shows me the value of the variable "live-weight-gain" (variable that updates every day), but I'm interested in having a monitor that shows the mean value of live-weight-gain seasonally (during the last 92 days).

Is there a way to have such a monitor in NetLogo?

-----------------EDITED-----------------------

Thanks for your responses @LeirsW and @adkane, but looks like I didn't explain myself correctly. The code provided by adkane reports the mean live-weight-gain of all turtles at the end of the season (day 92 of each season): it doesn't take into consideration what the live-weight-gain of turtles were during the last 92 days, and this is what I want: the mean live-weight-gain from day 1 to day 92.

I modified the code a little bit by adding stops at the end of the first 4 seasons (at 93, 185, 277 and 369 days).

```
globals [season]
turtles-own [live-weight-gain]


to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  crt 5
  [set live-weight-gain 0]
  
  ask n-of 40 patches [set pcolor green]
end

to go 
  ask turtles  
  [fd 1 
    if pcolor = green 
    [set live-weight-gain live-weight-gain + 1]]
  tick
  
  ; create season by tick
  ifelse ticks < 93 [set season "spring"] 
  [ifelse ticks > 92 and ticks < 183 [set season "summer"]
    [ifelse ticks > 182 and ticks < 277 [set season "autumn"] [set season "winter"] ]]
  if ticks  = 93 [ stop ]
  if ticks  = 185 [ stop ]
  if ticks  = 277 [ stop ]
  if ticks  = 369 [ stop ]
  
  ; reset energy gain by season
  ask turtles [
  if ticks = 93 or ticks = 185 or ticks = 277 [set live-weight-gain 0]
  ]
  
  ; measure the average at the end of the season
  if ticks = 92 [print mean [live-weight-gain] of turtles]
  if ticks = 184 [print mean [live-weight-gain] of turtles]
  if ticks = 276 [print mean [live-weight-gain] of turtles]
  if ticks = 368 [print mean [live-weight-gain] of turtles]
end
```

I added to the interface the next items:

A monitor called "Average LWG" with the code "mean [live-weight-gain] of turtles"

5 monitors, each of one for each of the five turtles of the system, called "Turtle 0 LWG"; "Turtle 1 LWG" and so on, with the code "[live-weight-gain] of turtle 0"; "[live-weight-gain] of turtle 1"; and so on.

A plot called "LWG" with 6 pens:

Average LWG "plot mean [live-weight-gain] of turtles"

Turtle 0 "plot [live-weight-gain] of turtle 0"

Turtle 1 "plot [live-weight-gain] of turtle 1"

And so on until Turtle 4...

I press go and, after the first stop occurs (at 93 days), the Command center and the "Average LWG" monitor shows, for example, 3.2 (I put the example of my run but ofc this will be random each run)

This 3.2 means that, at day 92, the average LWG of the five turtles is 3.2

But I don't want exactly this: I want to know the average of LWG for all turtles taking into account the values of LWG from day 1 to day 92, not only the last day (day 92, as it is right now in the code).

I have exported these results in an csv file writting in the Command center: export-plot "LWG" "LWG.csv"

When I open it with excel and I use the "=AVERAGE()" function giving it the LWG gains from day 1 to day 92, the output (in this case, because ofc it is random in each run) is 1.15. This is the value I want: a monitor in NetLogo that gives me the average of LWG from day 1 to day 92.

That is what I tried to explain in my other answer:

"For example, lets say I have one turtle in the system, and I want to know the mean live-weight-gain (LWG) value of that turtle for the last 5 days. Suppose the 1 day the LWG = 0.5, the 2 day = 0.25, 3 day = 1.75, 4 day = 1 and 5 day = 1.25. The mean LWG of the last 5 days is 0.95, this is the value I want to know, but your code shows me only the mean LWG of the last day (the 5th day in this case, which is 1.25). I want to apply this but instead for 5 days, for 92 days (i.e., at the end of each season)"

Hope I explained myself better this time!

Answer (score 0):

You could define your season based on your ticks like I've done here, but you can also just ask to print the mean value at set ticks so long as you reset the live-weight-gain at the end of each season.

```
globals [season]
turtles-own [live-weight-gain]


to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  crt 5
  [set live-weight-gain 0]
  
  ask n-of 40 patches [set pcolor green]
end

to go 
  ask turtles  
  [fd 1 
    if pcolor = green 
    [set live-weight-gain live-weight-gain + 1]]
  tick
  
  ; create season by tick
  ifelse ticks < 93 [set season "spring"] 
  [ifelse ticks > 92 and ticks < 183 [set season "summer"]
    [ifelse ticks > 182 and ticks < 277 [set season "autumn"] [set season "winter"] ]]
  if ticks  = 369 [ stop ]
  
  ; reset energy gain by season
  ask turtles [
  if ticks = 93 or ticks = 185 or ticks = 277 [set live-weight-gain 0]
  ]
  
  ; measure the average at the end of the season
  if ticks = 92 [print mean [live-weight-gain] of turtles]
  if ticks = 184 [print mean [live-weight-gain] of turtles]
  if ticks = 276 [print mean [live-weight-gain] of turtles]
  if ticks = 368 [print mean [live-weight-gain] of turtles]
end
```

Comment: Hi adkane! thanks for taking your time to help me and for your recommendation :-). I tried your example in NetLogo and seems that NetLogo is calculating the mean of live-weight-gain of the turtles at the end of each season. What I'm looking for is similar but not exactly that. What I want is to know the mean from day 1 to day 92.

Comment: For example, lets say I have one turtle in the system, and I want to know the mean live-weight-gain (LWG) value of that turtle for the last 5 days. Suppose the 1 day the LWG = 0.5,   the 2 day = 0.25,   3 day = 1.75,   4 day = 1 and  5 day = 1.25. The mean LWG of the last 5 days is 0.95. That is the value I would like to get from NetLogo (but instead of 5 days, the last 92 days). In your example NetLogo prints the mean LWG of X turtles at the end of each season. That info is also very valuable for me, but it doesn't take into account the LWG of turtles in the lasts 92 days of the season

Comment: @DiegoS What exactly is the problem? While in a season, do you want to know the mean live-weight-gain in that season so far, or do you always want the mean-live-weight gain for the last 92 days, regardless of in what season that day was?

Comment: @LeirsW Hi LeirsW! It would be the first case: while in a season, I want to know the mean live-weight-gain of all turtles in that season

Comment: @DiegoS That should work with the code that adkane provided here. At the start of each season the `live-weight-gain` of all turtles is reset to 0. So if at any point though the season, you call `mean [live-weight-gain] of turtles`, it will give you the mean `live-weight-gain` so far in that season. You can also use that as a reporter in a monitor, in order to constantly see it changing.

Comment: As @LeirsW points out, my answer is keeping track of the `live-weight-gain` throughout the simulation. You can pick when you want to extract it from the model or use a monitor to continuously record.

Comment: @LeirsW and adkane please read my answer in my editing question

Comment: Could you get rid of the `if ticks = x` part of my answer and run a behaviorspace experiment where you measure these values at every tick?